# Laravel constrained relationship won't return data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 7 and I'm encountering a problem with my constrained relationships not returning any data:

**Domain.php**

```
class Domain extends Model
{
    ...
    public function draws()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Draw');
    }
```

**Code in Controller:**

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();

    $domain = Domain::with(['draws' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 'ball_1')
            ->groupBy('date', 'ball_1');
    }])->get();

    dump($domain->first()->draws); // <---- Should return 2 elements
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

**Output**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#336 ▼
  #items: [] // <------- returns no elements
}
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `domains`"
    ...
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select DATE(created_at) as date, `ball_1` from `draws` where `draws`.`domain_id` in (1) group by `date`, `ball_1`"
    ...
  ]
]
```

If I execute the second query, I can retrieve both expected elements:
[image: Query in Adminer]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you'll need to select the foreign key to make `with` to work. If the fk is domain_id, try `$query->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 'ball_1', 'domain_id')...`

Comment: Works like a charm, you're my hero! Please put it as an answer 

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ May I ask which part of the documentation I missed where this is stated?

Comment: Well.. I don't have much more argument that happened to me once and I solved in this way. I'm commenting from mobile now, and to find the explanation I'd have to find the code for how `with` works.

Comment: Alright, no worries - when you get a chance, write your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Please check my answer. It explains why @porloscerros answer works! Consider marking his answer as correct, I just explained the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because you didn't selected the foreign key column.

Laravel eager loading for `hasMany` relation is loaded this way:

First it does one query to the main model table, in your case to `domains` table. With the results it make an array of primary keys returned (list of `id` column), for example `1, 2, 3`

With this ids, it will query related table with a where in clause:

```
where domain_id in (1, 2, 3)
```

This will return a list will all `draws` for the loaded domains. But this list is not linked yet with the domain. It will use the `domain_id` column from the second query to know which `draw` belongs to each `domain`.

If you didn't selected the `domain_id`, it won't be able to do the last step (`domain_id` will be null for all draws)

So you need to add `domain_id` to your select:

```
Domain::with(['draws' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 'ball_1', 'domain_id')
        ->groupBy('date', 'ball_1');
}])->get();
```

Or probably (didn't tested) you can just use `addSelect()` instead of `select()` since it won't remove the original selects created by Laravel:

```
Domain::with(['draws' => function ($query) {
    $query->addSelect(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 'ball_1')
        ->groupBy('date', 'ball_1');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Elias, for this exhaustive explanation - I learned something today 

Comment: I just tried the `addSelect()` and it won't work either, it returns empty collection.